# How can i prevent my application to be opened by other applications like sandbox etc

Tags: c#, process

I am developing an application which has a processes running. For some security requirements i dont want my application to be opened with any other application like sone file copier applications, sandbox etc. can you please guide me if it is possible using C#?

Comment: @GrantWinney, actually my program and its processes will already be running in a system. What i want is that when anyone tries to open my program, that is lets suppose "secure.exe" using any other application like Sandbox, file copier, debugger, emulator or anything even if antivirus is using it for scanning, in such cases my application should not run and should write the log that which app tried to open it.. It should only run when a user open it normally, using .exe extension.
Hope this makes you clear. 
P.S: sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,

```
public bool IsFileLocked(string filename)
        {
            bool Locked = false;
            try
            {
                FileStream fs =
                    File.Open(filename, FileMode. OpenOrCreate,
                    FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
                fs.Close();
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                Locked = true;
            }
            return Locked;
        }
```

Refered from : [How do I check whether a file is in use?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/dead0507-06f5-43e0-9250-a78437956bc8/faq-how-do-i-check-whether-a-file-is-in-use?forum=netfxbcl)

Comment: this code sets `Locked` flag even if there is no file.better first check wether file Exists or Not using `if(File.Exists(filename))`

Comment: my question isnt about locking the file, please read my comment in the question for more description. @SudhakarTillapudi.

Comment: There is a chance that the file may be locked milliseconds after you check it. The best way to check if the file is locked is by trying to open and use it and catching an exception if the file's already in use.